# One desktop session for multi user

Tags: windows, windows-7

We have a shared physical computer used to run test campaigns and we are using a generic user account. Currently, any team member who needs to run/monitor/analyze the tests will be given the generic user account's password.

Is there a solution that doesn't involve sharing generic user account's password? As this generic user credential is used elsewhere. I was thinking of each team member login using their own credential and they will be logged in to the same 'desktop session'. Is it possible?

NOTE: there is a specialized hardware needed for the test, and thus this solution involving generic user account being in place.

Comment: Is sensitive, restricted, or regulated data involved? If not, then what does it matter of they're using a shared username/password?

Comment: Indeed, 1) the sensitive and restricted is in the physical machine and 2) only people cleared for them will have the username/password. The problem is, the username/password is of LDAP account which can be used elsewhere. An option is to use local account but IT has policy against it (waiver is possible). So, I'm searching for options with the community.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the specialised hardware needs specific software to use it?

And that software probably doesn't support several different sessions using it at the same time ?   If this is the case, then **your current method is really the only workable solution**.

- *Option 1* To increase security, consider giving the shared account a unique password but share it, perhaps using some kind of "automated login" tool at the console.  After all, this is a physical device, so physical security can be used to control access.  You should disallow RDP on this account, and give it the minimum levels of permission required.
- *Option 2* The opposite of option 1, disallow physical access to this machine, and only permit the testing user to connect via RDP.  Use System logs to identify connections by their source IP on your office LAN.  Downside, if your specialised hardware requires physical access for the test.
- *Option 3* Make the kit mobile.  If its USB-connected or similar, set it up permanently on a mobile trolley, and users have to wheel it to their desk to do their testing.  This falls down if its an internal card, or too big to move around.
- *Option 4* The ideal solution would be to purchase this special hardware for each person who needs to do testing and install it in their work desktops.  Downsides, this could be significantly expensive to acquire and maintain, and that each item of gear will be used less overall.   Upside is that multiple users can do their testing simultaneously - really depends on your use case here.